# Shehechayanu for online transactions

Tags: halacha, internet, transactions, shehecheyanu, orach-chaim

The Shulchan Aruch ([OC 223:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%92_%D7%93)) rules one should recite shehecheyanu when making certain purchases of important new items. My question is whether they should recite it for an online  transaction, or if they have to be present to the item when they make it?

Comment: MB says that's only if it's immediately wearable. If you order online you'd probably need to wait till you receive it or use it.